# F-1 OPT STEM extension using my second Master's in a STEM degree

Tags: usa

I have a Master's in a non - STEM degree, and almost finishing my second master's in a STEM degree. I have already used my master's F-1 OPT ( 12 months). I am wondering if I can still apply for the the F-1 OPT STEM extension using my second Master's in a STEM degree.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you first did a (non-STEM) master's degree #1, followed by 12 months of OPT, and later started your second (STEM) master's degree #2. Then the answer is no. [You need to be on OPT while applying](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment/stem-opt#_Eligibility_for_the) for the STEM OPT *extension*. Yet you can't be on OPT, since you used up the 12 months from this degree level already.

Answer (score 1):

The limiting factor is that OPT can be authorized for only 12 months total per degree level.  If you had known you were going to get a second master's in a STEM field, it would have been wise to get your first OPT for less than 12 months.  For example, if your first OPT had been authorized for 9 months at master's level, you could apply for 3 months of OPT now, and then the 24 month STEM extension.  Unfortunately this option isn't available once you've already had 12 months of OPT at your current degree level.